# Repackaging a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I had to make some changes and I updated a file in an installed gem's folder.

How should I repackage this gem such that it gets updated as whole?

Answer (score 2):

To remake the `.gem` file, you can do a `gem build <gemspec>`. To push the gem to Rubygems.org, do a `gem push <built gem>`. See http://rubygems.org/ for more info.